# Scroll horizontally to a DIV and show a specific DIV inside

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I have a DIV container that contains two DIVs floated left. The second DIV contains a stack of three other DIVs. When I click a link inside the first DIV I want it to scroll to the next DIV(id="red") and show the appropriate DIV. For example, when I click on the link 'scroll-to-2', I want the container to scroll to the next DIV(id="red") and show the second DIV but hide the first and third. I'm trying to use the ScrollTo plugin.

Here is the start I made in jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/psivadasan/n9J57/2/

Appreciate any help.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="scrollable">
    <div id="blue" class="gray">
        <a class="scroll-1" href="#">Scroll to 1</a>
        <a class="scroll-2" href="#">Scroll to 2</a>
        <a class="scroll-3" href="#">Scroll to 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="red" class="red">
        <div class="card">1</div>
        <div class="card">2</div>
        <div class="card">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(‘#scroll-link-1’).click (function () {
$.scrollTo(‘#red’, 1000)});
```

CSS

```
.container {width: 400px;height: 200px;overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: hidden;}.scrollable {width: 800px;height: 200px;}.gray {width: 400px; height: 200px;background-color: gray; float: left;}.red {width: 400px; height: 200px;background-color: red; float: left;}.card {width: 400px; height: 200px; position: absolute;}
```

Comment: Usually I use anchors to achieve that. Simple and clear.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/n9J57/3/

Comment: @Spokey Looks like you have the answer there, Spokey. Nice fiddle.